# How to separately scale geoms with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, quantmod

I am attempting to combine these 2 plots into 1 but I can not figure out how to scale them separately when they are combined. I have scaled the second y axis to the proper level, but it does not adjust the data output on the plot.

The problem is the values of plot 1 range between 0:2 while the range of plot 2 is 0:150000 so even though I have scaled the second y axis, the data will not adjust to that scale. I have read that scale_y_continuous() only adjusts the axis and has no representation of the actual data.

So how would I separately scale each geom?

SETUP:

```
library(quantmod)
library(tidyverse)
SPY520 <- getOptionChain("SPY", "2022-05-20")
SPY1Mputs <- SPY520[["puts"]]
```

Plot 1:
[Plot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoUuW.png)

```
SPY1Mputs %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(x = Strike, y = IV)) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(x = Strike, y = IV))
```

Plot 2:
[Plot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sArDQ.png)

```
SPY1Mputs %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_col(aes(x = Strike, y = OI))
```

Attempted combine:
[Plot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kax78.png)

```
SPY1Mputs %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Strike)) + 
  geom_col(aes(y = OI)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = IV)) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(y = IV)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis((~./60000), name = "IV"))
```

Comment: `geom_col(aes(x = Strike, y = OI/60000))` should scale that data down. Keep in mind the secondary axis in ggplot2 is just a decoration and does not in itself scale the data.

Comment: Ah yes, this is perfect! Thank you for your prompt efficiency.